# Creeating a div with an ID and then modify it

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, frontend, e-commerce

First of all, i'm a newb to HTML and JS and my english is not the best so sorry about that.

I have an id on a HTML element. I want to add content to this element with a function and create another element (inside the first one), with a new ID and then modify this last ID with a function that runs after the first one.

The id i have defined in HTML is "product-container"

With the function "show product()" i want to create its content and to create a div for its images (id=images-div), which i will add with the function "appendImages()".

I honestly don't know how to do this with only 1 function becouse the item has multiple images and i dont know how to iterate them in a for inside the innerHTML. But i think i should be able to do it this way.

I'm not sure if the problem is that i'm defining the variable (let imagesDiv = document.getElementById("images-div")) before the element is created...

HTML Code:
`<div class="list-group"   id="product-container"> </div>`

JS Code:

```
const URL = PRODUCT_INFO_URL + localStorage.getItem("productID") + EXT_TYPE

let productContainer = document.getElementById("product-container")
let imagesDiv = document.getElementById("images-div")
let relatedProducts =document.getElementById("related-products")

let currentProduct = [];

function appendImages(){

    let HTMLContentToAppend = "";

    for (let productImage of product.images){
        HTMLContentToAppend +=`
        <div class="col-3">
            <img src="${productImage}" alt="${product.name}" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>`
    }

    imagesDiv.innerHTML = HTMLContentToAppend
}

function showProduct(){

    let product = currentProduct

    productContainer.innerHTML = `

        <div class="list-group-item">
            <h1> ${product.name} </h1>
            <hr>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="justify-content-between">
                        <h4 class="mb-1"> Precio </h4>
                        <p> ${product.currency} ${product.cost}
                    </div>
                    <div class="justify-content-between">
                        <h4 class="mb-1"> Descripción </h4>
                        <p> ${product.description}
                    </div>
                    <div class="justify-content-between">
                        <h4 class="mb-1"> Categoría </h4>
                        <p> ${product.category}
                    </div>
                    <div class="justify-content-between">
                        <h4 class="mb-1"> Cantidad de Vendidos </h4>
                        <p> ${product.soldCount}
                    </div>
                    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3" id="images-div">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>`;

    appendImages()
};
```

Thanks in advance for the help and sorry for the newby question :/

Answer (score 0):

What you assumed to be the problem is actually the problem. Move `let imagesDiv = document.getElementById("images-div")` inside the `appendImages` function.